# Problems syncing wallet

Tags: mist, wallets, synchronization, hardforks

I have been unsuccessful in trying to sync a new wallet or mist. I deleted the blockchain data and started over and it seemed to be syncing quite fast again, was more than halfway done in a few hours. I left it overnight and in the morning it was starting over again, was only at block 4000. I'm wondering if I should just wait for the next hardfork? Isn't it supposed to address some of these syncing issues?